# How do I pass parameters to a MailerPreview class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning how to send emails with ActionMailer in rails, and I am having trouble passing parameters into my OrderMailerPreview class. I need to pass an order_id into the new_order method so I can look up the appropriate order. Here is the code:

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/order_mailer
class OrderMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  # Preview this email at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/order_mailer/new_order
  def new_order(order_id)
    @order = Shoppe::Order.find(order_id)
    OrderMailer.new_order(order)
  end

end
```

How can I get that order_id into this method?

Answer (score 0):

[`ActionMailer::Preview`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Previewing+emails) is simply made to render previews with fake or seeded data and does not support param passing as far as I know. Rather it simply uses the url to locate files based on class / method. This corresponds with its intended use as a development aid.

If you need to use dynamic data in the mailer previews or for example make the preview viewable to end users you should instead create a controller which renders the mailer view.

```
class OrderMailerPreviewController < ApplicationController
  # GET /mailers_previews/orders/:id
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    render "mailers/order", layout: nil
  end
end
```